# Same height and width but not Square

Tags: html, css

I tried the following

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;border:solid 5px;"></div>
```

But it doesn't seems to be `square`

Tested in different `browsers and machines`, still not `square`, its a `rectangle`

Could anyone please explain why this is happening??

Comment: @ Zword : Can you explain why?

Comment: Looks square to me. http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/57Qxj/ What's the problem?

Comment: try replicating the issue in sample. It seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/t9wJH/

Comment: Your display has higher than wider pixels???

Comment: @Hardy:Whether it depends on our screen resolution?

Comment: Just try with small pixels, say 200px or 100px

Comment: it might have to do with the way screen resolutions work

Comment: @Zword: Could you reply as answer, with descriptions and what you tried?

Comment: @Jaykishan:First try then talk